# What simple step is on this javascript, php, display failure missing? can't figure it out

Tags: javascript, php, css, displaytag, displayobject

this is the code:

```
<?php $countrycode=$p["country"]; ?>
<select size="1" name="countrycode" id="countrycode" onchange="javascript:
    if(this.value=='USA') { 
        document.getElementById('us').style.display='block';
    } else { 
        document.getElementById('us').style.display='none';
    } 
    if(this.value=='DE') {
        document.getElementById('de').style.display='block';
    } else { 
        document.getElementById('de').style.display='none';
    }
">
    <option value="INT" <?php 
        if($countrycode=='INT') { echo 'selected="selected"'; } ?> 
    >International</option>
    <option value="USA" <?php
        if($countrycode=='USA') { echo 'selected="selected"'; } ?> 
    >USA</option>
    <option value="DE" <?php
        if($countrycode=='DE') { echo 'selected="selected"'; } ?> 
    >DE</option>
</select>
```

This is what I get as result:

When it is the value 'DE' nothing appears below.

**When it is the value 'USA' all (even the ones for 'DE') appears.
Like this:**

Also allow:  Canada  ¦   United Kingdom ¦  Australia display:none;" id="de"> (>> last part shouldn't be displayed - means display:none;" id="de">)

Also allow:  Switzerland   Austria  (>> this should actually displays on value 'DE')

Would very appreciate a solution that is helping me out.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do here? It seems like you're making things way more complicated than they should be. If at all possible, you should separate out content from functionality.

Comment: Please, please *do not* use inline JavaScript.  As you can see, it makes your code a mess.  Use `document.getElementById('countrycode').addEventListener('change', function(){})`.

Comment: document.getElementById('us') and document.getElementById('de') where are the elements with these ID's?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the missing echo (just forgot)

```
<?php if($countrycode=='USA') { echo 'display:block;'; } else { echo 'display:none;'; }
 ?>
```

" id="us">
Also allow:

value="1"> Canada

```
<?php
     if($p["UK"]=='1') { echo 'checked="checked"'; } ?>
```

value="1"> United Kingdom

```
<?php 
    if($p["AU"]=='1') { echo 'checked="checked"'; } ?>
```

value="1"> Australia

```
<?php if($countrycode=='DE') { echo 'display:block;'; } else { echo 'display:none;'; } ?>
```

" id="de">
Also allow:

value="1"> Switzerland

```
<?php 
if($p["AT"]=='1') { echo 'checked="checked"'; } ?>
```

value="1"> Austria

Comment: to write all new would be very timeconsuming. cause it is a prepared script it's written as it is. i just added a new function - all working fine beside of this tiny code result.

Answer (score 0):

JS Fiddle example of a better way to do this:

http://jsfiddle.net/m55nb59x/1/

HTML:

```
<select id="countrycode" name="countrycode">
    <option value="INT">International</option>
    <option value="USA">USA</option>
    <option value="DE">DE</option>
</select>
<div id="us">USA div</div>
<div id="de">DE div</div>
<div id="int">INT div</div>
```

JS:

```
var selectedCountry = '<? echo $p["country"]; ?>';
//var selectedCountry = 'USA'; // for testing
var divs = $('#us, #de, #int');
var countryCodeSelector = $('#countrycode');
countryCodeSelector.val(selectedCountry);
selectCountry(selectedCountry);
countryCodeSelector
    .change(
        function() {
            var code = $(this).val();
            selectCountry(code);
        }
    )
;
function selectCountry(code){
    var selectedID = '';
    switch(code){
        case 'USA':
            selectedID = 'us';
            break;
        case 'DE':
            selectedID = 'de';
            break;
        case 'INT':
            selectedID = 'int';
            break;
    }
    divs.hide();
    $('#' + selectedID).show();
}
```

There is further optimization to be done, but this works (like setting up a mapping between Country values, IDs, and titles.